# Uploading file to server and getting its path into a MySQL variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just trying the basic way of uploading image to my web server with this HTML code;

```
<form action="forgotten.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

And this is my forgotten.php;

```
 $response = array();
 $text =""; /*create variable to save data */
 $file = $_FILES['file'];
 $name = $file['name'];


 $path = "/uploads/" . basename($name);
 if (isset($_POST['name'])) {


$name = $_POST['name'];
$file = $_POST['file'];

$description = $_POST['description'];

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . 'http://www.buiud.com/android_connect/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (path) VALUES ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($path) . "')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";
}  
}                         
 ?>
```

And MySQL database contains the two Varchar path and BLOB file variables

The php file doesn't show any errors or anything, it just never shows up in the database.

I have put a folder called uploads inside the same folder with the two scripts.

Comment: Show the db schema. Also, you are mixing `mysql_` (which is deprecated) and `MySQLi`. And you are not using prepared statements.

Comment: And you never write anything into `$path`.

Comment: And having you `db_connect.php` script world (literally) readable, is also not a good idea.

Comment: `require_once __DIR__ . 'http://www.buiud.com/…'` – what’s this nonsense? It makes no sense to concatenate the current dir with an HTTP URL, and including via HTTP makes no sense in such a case either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your php code to this:(make changes accordingly) and save path as VARCHAR or CHAR

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");    
$allowedExts = array(
"pdf", 
"doc", 
"txt"
); 

$allowedMimeTypes = array( 
'application/msword',
'text/pdf',
'image/gif',
'image/jpeg',
'image/png',
'text/plain'
);

$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ( 20000 < $_FILES["file"]["size"]  ) 
{
    echo"Please provide a smaller file [E/1].";
}


if ( in_array( $_FILES["file"]["type"], $allowedMimeTypes ) ) 
{  
    $file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $filePath = "upload/" . $file;    
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$filePath); 
}

else if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]))
{
    $file='';
    $filePath='';
}
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_name (path) VALUES ('$filePath')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending of the local settings errors are not always showed. To ensure that errors are showed add the following lines at the top :

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Then try it again. Is it still showing not errors?